# How to trigger the event without input enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate the sum of a column consisting multiple row
the values are retrieved from the database and can also be manually alter/
The issue is without the input event, the function are not triggered.
So when the column display multiple rows value, the total amount wont show.
Any idea.Thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
$("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
       var calculated_total_sum = 0;
     
       $("#myTable .txtCal").each(function () {
           var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
           if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
              calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
              }                  
            });
              $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
       });
       
    

});
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>   <th width="100">Name </th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span>A :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><span>B :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal'  value="10"/></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td><span>C :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
</tr>  

<tr>
    <td><span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span></td>
    <td><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Put everything inside your input listener into a separate function and call it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
$("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
       calculate();
});


function calculate() {
var calculated_total_sum = 0;
     
       $("#myTable .txtCal").each(function () {
           var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
           if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
              calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
              }                  
            });
              $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
}
       
calculate();
    

});
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>   <th width="100">Name </th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span>A :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><span>B :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal'  value="10"/></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td><span>C :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
</tr>  

<tr>
    <td><span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span></td>
    <td><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move code that calculates price to separate function and call it on 'domready' and 'input' events.

Answer (score 1):

This may helpful

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var calculated_total_sum;
  calSum();
  
  
       
       
$("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
      
      calSum();
       
       });
       
    function calSum()
    {
      calculated_total_sum=0;
      $("#myTable .txtCal").each(function () {
           var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
           if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
              calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
              }                  
            });
              $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
    }

});
```

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>   <th width="100">Name </th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span>A :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td><span>B :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal'  value="10"/></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
    <td><span>C :</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='txtCal' value="10" /></td>
</tr>  

<tr>
    <td><span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span></td>
    <td><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change when the event calculate the value. In your code, you triggered the calculation when the txtCal class are input. You have to create a separate function like this:

```
function calculate() {
    var calculated_total_sum = 0;

    $("#myTable .txtCal").each(function () {
       var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
       if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
          calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
          }                  
        });
        $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
   });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    calculate();

    $("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
        calculate();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate function and call it on `input` and to get the sum when page gets ready with values from database, call it inside document.ready like given below:

```
function getSum()
{
    $("#myTable .txtCal").each(function () {
           var calculated_total_sum = 0;
           var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
           if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
              calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
              }                  
            });
              $("#total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
       });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    getSum();

    $("#myTable").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
        getSum();
    });
});
```